# ¿Como cambiar tamaño de letra en input?

Tags: html, css, input

Estoy teniendo problemas al cambiar el tamaño de letra de los inputs cuando se ingresa texto

Quiero que se cambie el tamaño de la letra del input al ingresar texto, pero al hacerlo también me cambia el tamaño del input, lo que debe ser diferente

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que al cambiar el tamaño de la letra del input al ingresar texto, no me cambie el tamaño del input?

Esto es lo que he hecho

```css
.form-group input[type=text],
.form-group select{
    font-size: 12px;
    padding-left: 1em;
    padding-right: 1em;
    color: #C5CCE1;
    height: 1.875em;
    border-radius: 9px;
    outline: none;
    border: 1px solid #C0C8E7;
    width: 24.25em;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" name="mdl_add_nombre" id="mdl_add_nombre" class="mdl_input_proveedor">
    <label>Nombre de Proveedor</label>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <select name="mdl_add_nacionalidad" id="mdl_add_nacionalidad" class="mdl_input_proveedor">
        <option value="">>> Seleccione una opción</option>
        <option value="">Internacional</option>
        <option value="">Nacional</option>
    </select>
    <label>Nacionalidad</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Estas usando como unidad de medidad `em` la cual es relativa al tamaño de letra del elemento, deberías considerar usar otra unidad como `rem`, `px` etc.

Comment: Gracias. No había tomado eso en cuenta. Funciona ahora

Answer (score 1, accepted):

la unidad de medida `em` se basa al tamaño de texto actual, por lo que quiere decir que si tu tamaño de letra es más grande, el tamaño del input también va a ser afectada.

Tendrías que usar la unidad de medida `px`, en donde haciendo la conversión de `1.875em` a `px` sería `30px`, ejemplo:

```css
.form-group input[type=text],
.form-group select{
  font-size: 25px;
  padding-left: 1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
  color: #C5CCE1;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 9px;
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid #C0C8E7;
  width: 24.25em;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" name="mdl_add_nombre" id="mdl_add_nombre" class="mdl_input_proveedor">
  <label>Nombre de Proveedor</label>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <select name="mdl_add_nacionalidad" id="mdl_add_nacionalidad" class="mdl_input_proveedor">
    <option value="">>> Seleccione una opción</option>
    <option value="">Internacional</option>
    <option value="">Nacional</option>
  </select>
  <label>Nacionalidad</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Ahora si, logré hacerlo. Exactamente era por las unidades de medida. Gracias